# fetch response text from ajax response of a dropzone

Tags: javascript, ajax, dropzone.js

I've got the following response from dropzone successful upload.

[image]

From this I need to fetch the responseText

I tried: `console.log(response.xhr.responseText)` this show the full response text.

When i try to fetch `img` from responseText like this `console.log(response.xhr.responseText.img)` the console throw `undefined`

Comment: It looks like you might be using a JavaScript library (something like BlueImp's fileUpload), but I can't tell. It might help to clarify whether you're using a library to handle this, and what that library is.

Comment: I'm using dropzone.js

Answer (score 9):

In your sample, the value of `rexponse.xhr.responseText` is a string, not an object.  You can parse the string into an object and access the `img` property:

`(JSON.parse(response.xhr.responseText)).img`

...but, since Dropzone `success` events get both the `file` object and the parsed `responseText`, you could write a `success` handler like this:

```
new Dropzone("#myUploader", { 
    url: "/upload",
    init: function () {
      this.on("success", function (file, responseText) {
        console.log(responseText.img);
      });
    }
});
```

for more information, check out [the FAQ](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#i-want-to-display-additional-information-after-a-file-uploaded).

Answer (score 3):

[Saurabh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4838791/saurabh-wankhede) solution is working for me after making some changes, beacuse i was getting

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

when trying

```
init: function () { 
this.on("success", function (file, responseText) { 
var responsetext = JSON.parse(responseText); 
console.log(responsetext.file_name); });
```

so i made some changes in it and its working for me.

```
this.on("success", function (file) {
                var responsetext = JSON.parse(file.xhr.responseText);
                console.log(responsetext);});
```

Answer (score 0):

new Dropzone("#myUploader", { 
    url: "/upload",
    init: function () {
      this.on("success", function (file, responseText) {
        var responsetext = JSON.parse(responseText); 
        console.log(responsetext.file_name);
      });
    }
});