# dropzone plugin access xhr response ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, dropzone.js

Using dropzone.js jquery plugin i need to access/read this xhr.response, but always return null/empty:

**sending event of dropzone:**

[image]

**Response:**

[image: console.log response]
**console.log("sending file:", file);**
[image: ajax response]

what my html form i'm using this, like dropzone example:
[image: Form]

I also try use $(document).ajaxComplete to "catch" the ajax event from the form, but dropping the image to form, ajaxComplete dont assume this kind of ajaxRequests.

Yes, i know the dropzone plugin already return the uploaded image name, but in my ajax request i store the image on server, and change the name of picture and i need the new name of image.

I know too i can use the same ajax of treatment of image to cacth the name of image, but when create the product the first time, i don't have the product ID in BD to know which product i need to associate the image, where that's the reason i need to read the XHR.response, to get the new name image saved in server.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `console.log(file.xhr.response);`return response inside of xhr request or `console.log(file.xhr);` return complete xhr request.
i hope it helpe.

**Edit**

From an other similar quest i found this [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30276067/5118277) solution and it's working for me, you can do as.

```
var responsetext = JSON.parse(file.xhr.responseText);
                console.log(responsetext.data.name);
```

My response looks something like this . `{"status":1,"data":{"name":"Coursesicon","path":"category1\/courses_icon_9c3c166bc58d6c77b83cb469baeb7f0cc9c8105c.png","updated_at":"2015-09-23 05:40:22","created_at":"2015-09-23 05:40:22","id":112}}`